# Web-GL : Multiple Fragment Shaders per Program

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

Does anyone know if it's possible to have multiple fragment shaders run serially in a single Web-GL "program"?  I'm trying to replicate some code I have written in WPF using shader Effects.  In the WPF program I would wrap an image with multiple borders and each border would have an Effect attached to it (allowing for multiple Effects to run serially on the same image).

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid you're probably going to have to clarify your question a bit, but I'll take a stab at answering anyway:

WebGL can support, effectively, as many different shaders as you want. (There are of course practical limits like available memory but you'd have to be trying pretty hard to bump into them by creating too many shaders.) In fact, most "real world" WebGL/OpenGL applications will use a combination of many different shaders to produce the final scene rendered to your screen. (A simple example: Water will usually be rendered with a different shader or set of shaders than the rest of the environment around it.)

When dispatching render commands only one shader program may be active at a time. The currently active program is specified by calling `gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);` after which any geometry drawn will be rendered with that program. If you want to render an effect that requires multiple different shaders you will need to group them by shader and draw each batch separately:

```
 gl.useProgram(shader1);
 // Setup shader1 uniforms, bind the appropriate buffers, etc.
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, shader1VertexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // Draw geometry that uses shader1

 gl.useProgram(shader2);
 // Setup shader2 uniforms, bind the appropriate buffers, etc.
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, shader2VertexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // Draw geometry that uses shader2

 // And so on...
```

Comment: How is synchronization done between stages ?  For the snippet above, it looks as though there is an assumption that stage X finishes way faster than the Javascript code for stage X+1 to be set up.

Comment: Are you mixing up the words "program" and "shader"? Shaders are attached to programs, which are linked to the webgl context. What about multiple vertex shaders or multiple fragment shaders in a single program?

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are on the right track. You'd either need to create the shader on the fly that applies all the effects in one shader or framebuffers and apply the effects one at a time. There's an example of the later here

[WebGL Image Processing Continued](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)

Comment: I have been following your tutorials for the past week. They are very helpful and thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 4):

As Toji suggested, you might want to clarify your question. If I understand you correctly, you want to apply a set of post-processing effects to an image.

The simple answer to your question is: No, you can't use multiple fragment shaders with one vertex shader.

However, there are two ways to accomplish this: First, you can write everything in one fragment shader and combine them in the end. This depends on the effects you want to have!
Second, you can write multiple shader programs (one for each effect) and write your results to a fragment buffer object (render to texture). Each shader would get the results of the previous effect and apply the next one. This would be a bit more complicated, but it is the most flexible approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to run several shaders in a single render pass, like so (example pulled from thin air):

1. Vertex color
2. Texture
3. Lighting
4. Shadow

...each stage attached to a single `WebGLProgram` object, and each stage with its own `main()` function, then no, GLSL doesn't work this way.

GLSL works more like C/C++, where you have a single global `main()` function that acts as your program's entry point, and any arbitrary number of libraries attached to it. The four examples above could each be a separate "library," compiled on its own but linked together into a single program, and invoked by a single `main()` function, but they may not each define their own `main()` function, because such definitions in GLSL are shared across the entire program.

This unfortunately requires you to write separate `main()` functions (at a minimum) for every shader you intend to use, which leads to a *lot* of redundant programming, even if you plan to reuse the libraries themselves. That's why I ended up writing a glorified string mangler to manage my GLSL libraries for [Jax](http://blog.jaxgl.com/what-is-jax); I'm not sure how useful the code will be outside of my framework, but you are certainly free to take a look at it, and make use of anything you find helpful. The relevant files are:

- [lib/assets/javascripts/jax/shader.js.coffee](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/jax/blob/b64d3c92bc2da27898e448f1ad38d683ed0b5e82/lib/assets/javascripts/jax/shader.js.coffee)
- [lib/assets/javascripts/jax/shader/program.js.coffee](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/jax/blob/b64d3c92bc2da27898e448f1ad38d683ed0b5e82/lib/assets/javascripts/jax/shader/program.js.coffee)
- [spec/javascripts/jax/shader_spec.js.coffee](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/jax/blob/b64d3c92bc2da27898e448f1ad38d683ed0b5e82/spec/javascripts/jax/shader_spec.js.coffee) (tests and usage examples)
- [spec/javascripts/jax/shader/program_spec.js.coffee](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/jax/blob/b64d3c92bc2da27898e448f1ad38d683ed0b5e82/spec/javascripts/jax/shader/program_spec.js.coffee) (more tests and usage examples)

Good luck!